# Pages show all rows when using get_context_Data for paginate_by in ListView

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

The pagination in this simple generic view in Django is working, but each page displays all rows, and not the rows for that page.
How can I select the only the records needed for a given page?

```
class ArticleList(ListView):
    """Get all articles"""
    model = Article
    template_name = "blog/articles.html"
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = Article.objects.select_related().all()

        return context
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you've overridden the `articles` object in `get_context_data` to return everything. The default implementation does the pagination there, but you've replaced that with your non-paginated queryset.

Instead, define `get_queryset` and add the `select_related` there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I ended up solving it at first:

```
class ArticleList(ListView):
"""Get all articles"""
model = Article
template_name = "blog/articles.html"
paginate_by = 1

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    p = Paginator(Article.objects.select_related().all(), self.paginate_by)
    context['articles'] = p.page(context['page_obj'].number)

    return context
```

However, after everyones help the best way is:

```
class ArticleList(ListView):
"""Get all articles"""
model = Article
template_name = "blog/articles.html"
paginate_by = 1
context_object_name = "articles"

def get_queryset(self):
    return Article.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Please, check the answer of daniel-roseman, also this can help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Thank you, `context_object_name` seems useful